# How to remove <div ...> tags in a Excel cell with much HTML code?

Tags: excel, search, replace

i scraped datas from a website using Python. The results are great.
Just the after-work-party is something annoying.

The HTML source code is (of course) messed up with various kind of `div class="abc123">` tags.

Do we have an Excel geek-trick to remove them quickly?

I search a `<div ...>` tag manually and remove the specified one via search'n replace function.
After I jump to the next div tag and so on....

Isn't it a little bit too much of the "good old school" way to remove it?
Of course, there are some online services (free and paid) to do that, but I'm sure we have a trick in Excel, I just can't get it out right now. And using external services like an online tool for cleaning HTML code is again a extra workload - unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting around with some RegEx I was able to solve my problem:

Pressing `Ctrl` `+` `H` for opening `Find and Replace` then entering my pattern `<div *>` and replacing it with - whatever:

- Find what: `<div *>`
- Replace with:

That's it. Finally.